# Pylint not working within Spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, pylint

I've installed Anaconda on a Windows computer and Spyder works fine, but running pylint through the Static Code Analysis feature gives an error. Pylint was installed through Conda.

Note: Error in Spyder would not allow me to copy and paste text directly. Used a picture to text converter to get the code below so there may be a few characters off...

```
No config file found, using default configuration Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C: \Users\ Username \AppData \Local \Continuum \Anaconda \Scripts\pylint-script.py", line 2, in <module> 
run_pylint() 
File "C: \Users\ USERNAME \AppData \Local \Continuum \Anaconda \lib\site-packages\pylint\_init_.py", line 23, in run_pylint 
Run(sys.argv[1:]) 
File "C: \Users\ USERNAME \AppData \Local \Continuum \Anaconda \lib\site-packages\pylint\lint.py", line 1313, in _init_ 
lintercheck(args) 
File "C: \Users\ USERNAME \AppData \Local \Continuum \Anaconda \lib\site-packages\pylint\lint.py", line 729, in check 
self._do_check(files_or_modules) 
File "C: \Users\ USERNAME \AppData \Local \Continuum \Anaconda \lib\site-packages\pylint\lint.py", line 831, in _do_check 
for descr in self.expand_files(files_or_modules): 
File "C: \Users\ USERNAME \AppData \Local \Continuum \Anaconda \lib\site-packages\pylint\lint.py", line 872, in expand_files 
self.add_message(key, args=message) 
File "C: \Users\ USERNAME \AppData \Local \Continuum \Anaconda \lib\site-packages\pylint\utils.py", line 390, in add_message 
self.stats['by_moduld][self.current_name][msg_cat] += 1 
KeyError: None
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on a resolution? Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a snippet to reproduce it?

Comment: This occurs when I click "Analyze" in the Static Code Analysis section regardless of the code I have inputted. I have tried with a simple print statement in the editing window, but the error still came up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you press F8 (Source> Run Static Code Analysis) this should work.

The analyse button in the pane tells it to analyse whatever file is in the Static code analysis drop down to the left of the button.  If there is nothing in there it seems to get very confused.

Pressing F8 autopopulates the drop down with the current file being edited, so saves you navigating to wherever it is.

Answer (score 2):

Previously I had been clicking into the editor and then hitting "Analyze" through the Static Code Analysis feature which was producing the error above.

If instead, I clicked on the folder within the Static Code Analysis pane and browsed to the .py file, the Static Code Analysis seemed to run appropriately without an error!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on Arch Linux, Python 3.4.3, PyLint 1.4.4.

If I use instead Python 2.7, it works as expected. I guess Spyder/Pylint doesn't work well with Python 3.

This is assuming you're using Python 3.

Comment: I checked and it seems that I do have Python 2.7 installed.

Comment: @EmilyK And are you sure it's Python 2.7 that's being used here? If so, then it might be a configuration issue which I couldn't begin to help you with :/

Comment: Yes, I've confirmed this is Python 2.7.9. After seeing this error I uninstalled Anaconda. I then reinstalled Python and pylint through Anaconda but I still see the error.

Comment: If it is a configuration do you know how or where I could begin to resolve the issue? Thanks.

Comment: Report the bug to the guys distributing the broken software! Anaconda of course. If they don't want to help, you could try Spyder devs, but I'd go through Anaconda first.

Answer (score -1):

[Pylint using F8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJ0kY.jpg) It is working well by pressing the F8 button once you have saved your file. Keep Analyzing